# PHP Curl API GET Call using authorization key and secret

Tags: api, curl, php-7.1

I am using PHP Curl to make a GET Call to an API (manheim api). 
Below is the code I am using :

```
$vin    = 'abc.............';
$atoken = 'xzc.......................';

$request_headers   = array();
$request_headers[] ='Authorization: Bearer: '.$atoken;
$request_headers[] ='Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

$handle  = curl_init();
$api_url = 'https://api.manheim.com/descriptions/capture/vin/'.$vin;    

$rawPostData = array( 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials', 'client_id' => 'xzc.......................', 'client_secret' => '6sd.......' ); 
// $data_string     = json_encode($rawPostData);

$data_string = '';

//create name value pairs seperated by &
foreach($rawPostData as $k => $v) 
{ 
    $data_string .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
}

rtrim($data_string, '&');

curl_setopt_array(
    $handle,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => $api_url,
        CURLOPT_POST            => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $data_string,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => $request_headers,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => -1
    )
);

$data = curl_exec($handle);
echo serialize($data);
```

I am getting the following in response:

"HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Content-Type: text/xml Date: Fri, 19 Jan 2018 06:44:21 GMT Server: Mashery Proxy WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api.manheim.com" X-Error-Detail-Header: Account Inactive X-Mashery-Error-Code: ERR_403_DEVELOPER_INACTIVE X-Mashery-Responder: prod-j-worker-us-east-1e-123.mashery.com Content-Length: 27 Connection: keep-alive
**Developer Inactive**

It is showing "Developer inactive". I am not sure where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have added a colon(:) after the 'Bearer'. Remove it and it should work. Authorization header should look like `Authorization: Bearer myvalidtoken`

The header `X-Mashery-Error-Code: ERR_403_DEVELOPER_INACTIVE` is added by mashery when you are not authenticated properly. The reason can be

1. 'Authorization' header has incorrect values
2. Token is created with incorrect api key(which donot have access to that endpoint)
3. Your valid token is expired and already deleted(normaly after 1 hour of expiry) from mashery database